# Trouble setting CSRF token in sending a tweet from a Golang Buffalo webapp

Tags: go, csrf, buffalo

I am having trouble with a Go Buffalo web app I am trying to build. I basically have a standard form on the front end that, when clicked, is supposed to send a tweet to the Users twitter account.
I get a "500: CSRF Not found" when doing so.
I am using the Go [Buffalo](https://github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo) framework for the web app and [go-twitter](https://github.com/dghubble/go-twitter) to handle the twitter API.

I have little to no experience with CSRF so was hoping somebody could help me in this specific case.

The tweet.HTML:

```
<h3>Tweet tweet!</h3>
<form action="/tweet" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tweet">Your tweet:</label>
        <input type="text" name="tweet" class="form-control" id="tweet" placeholder="Tweet body" 
        value="">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
```

The router:

```
app.POST("/tweet", SendHandler)
```

Tweet.go (Contains SendHandler function):

```
package actions

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "twitapp/twitter"

    "github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo"
)

var creds = twitter.Credentials{
    AccessToken:       os.Getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN"),
    AccessTokenSecret: os.Getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"),
    APIKey:            os.Getenv("API_KEY"),
    APISecret:         os.Getenv("API_SECRET"),
}

type TweetForm struct {
    TweetBody string
}

// TweetHandler is the handler for the Tweet page
func TweetHandler(c buffalo.Context) error {
    return c.Render(200, r.HTML("tweet.html"))
}

//SendHandler Function used by tweet.html to send the tweet/
//Takes in variables from twitter/server.go
func SendHandler(c buffalo.Context) error {

    var form TweetForm
    body := form.TweetBody

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", creds)

    //Gets the client from the twitter package
    client, err := twitter.GetClient(&creds)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error getting Twitter Client")
        log.Println(err)
    }

    //Sending the actual tweet. Body from the form
    tweet, resp, err := client.Statuses.Update(body, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    log.Printf("%+v\n", resp)
    log.Printf("%+v\n", tweet)
    return c.Redirect(302, "/tweet/confirm")

}
```

There is also a GetClient function that is called from the SendHandler function but I cant imagine the problem is in there as it standard code that sets up the twitter client for the call.
Appreciate any help/pointing in the right direction. I dont have enough knowledge of CSRF to apply it to this at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the GoBuffalo docs, and in particular [THIS](https://gobuffalo.io/en/docs/forms#how-do-i-handle-csrf-tokens-if-i-use-my-own-form) part of the forms page, All i had to do was add this line of code to my form (tweet.html) to handle the authenticity token.

```
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="<%= authenticity_token %>">
```

Answer (score 1):

[CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) is a kind of attack Buffalo is trying to protect you from.

To do that, it uses the [CSRF middleware](https://github.com/gobuffalo/mw-csrf) which checks every request which can mutate your data (eg. POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.) and looks for a specific token. **In your use-case, Buffalo expects you to send an input field named "authenticity_token"**, with the value the CSRF middleware put in the context. You can find this value at the same "authenticity_token" key in the context.

Another solution is to use the tags helpers (https://github.com/gobuffalo/tags) library which generates this expected input for you: https://github.com/gobuffalo/tags/wiki/Form

Comment: I used this instead of using framework: https://github.com/justinas/nosurf

Comment: This was helpful thank you. Turns out i had to include one line of code in my form to include the CSRF helper